# Delete word or whole line part after cursor in colon-command mode with keybinding

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, command-line

I would like my NeoVim to have Emacs-style keybindings in all "direct input" modes, in particular - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> for forward word and line part deleting. I've done it for insert mode as

```
inoremap <M-d> <C-o>de
inoremap <C-k> <C-o>d$
```

But couldn't fine a way for colon-command mode - there is no <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> analog. Is it possible at all?

Also, is it possible to perform undo in colon-command mode? In bash(with default Emacs-style keybindings) one can perform undo with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>. And in vim insert mode it could be mapped as `inoremap <C-_> <C-o>u` but I failed to find a way of mapping it in colon-command mode.

Comment: Your last question about undo is unclear (you don't explain what the problem with it is) and is fairly unrelated to the bulk of the question that talks about command-line mode. Please post that as a separate question and explain what doesn't work there, or what you want to achieve with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can handle command-line editing in Vim mappings.

For starters, there's [`CTRL-\ e`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-%5C_e) which allow you to fully replace the contents of the command-line with the result of an expression. (The documentation at `:help c_CTRL-\_e` has example usage.)

In general, you can use [`getcmdline()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#getcmdline%28%29) to find what is currently in the command-line, in order to pick the parts that you want. There's also `getcmdpos()` and `setcmdpos()` to find where the cursor is or change its position.

An alternative to replacing the whole command-line is to emulate the action you want to implement by using repeated use of different keystrokes. For example, if you want a mapping to delete to the end of the current word, you could use `getcmdline()` and `getcmdpos()` to find how many characters are left in the word and then produce that number of "Delete" keystrokes, which you can easily do with `repeat("\<Del>", n)` and is well suited for a `cnoremap <expr>` kind of mapping.

---

If you care about command-line editing (and who among us doesn't?), rather than implementing a bunch of pinky-strain-inducing mappings for it, you might consider using the command-line window, which you can enter using [`q:`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#q%3A) from Normal mode, or `CTRL-F` from the command-line, where you can use Vim's other modes (Normal and Insert mode) to edit your command-line before having it executed. You also have access to the command-line history as lines in that window, which you can browse with `k` and `j`, or search with `?`, etc.

Comment: with CapsLock remapping there is almost no pinky strain)

Comment: Remembered this in my dotfiles, but can’t find the Q&A :( https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/commit/0832f51d1810fa87276bbb6fe4b150ad9e1471cf